# Saving output of a function as a variable and using it in another function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I'm new to programming, so this question might be dumb.

I need to introduce the value of `Tr1` into the `Bzero1` function. When I run the module I get the result below:

[image: this result].

The program is not running the `Bzero1` function and I'm not sure why. Is it because I am not introducing the `Tr1` value correctly or something else? I want `Bzero1` to perform the operation `0.083-(0.422/Tr1**1.6)`, with `Tr1` obtained from the result of `T/Tc1`.

I would appreciate your help a lot.

```
T = float(input("Introduce system temperature in Kelvin: ")) 
print("System temperature is: ", T)

Tc1 = float(input("Introduce critical temperature of component 1: ")) 
print("Critical temperature of component 1 is: ", Tc1)

def Tr1(T, Tc1):
  print("Relative temperature 1: ", T/Tc1)

Tr1 = Tr1(T, Tc1)

def Bzero1(Tr1):
  print("Bzero 1: ", 0.083-(0.422/Tr1**1.6))
```

Comment: You never *call* the `Bzero1` function.

Comment: You are also replacing the name `Tr1` (a function)` with the return value of that function. But your function *never returns anything explicitly*, so you end up with `Tr1` set to `None`. `print()` writes to your console or terminal, it doesn't return anything for you to assign to a variable.

Comment: Please don't link to screenshots of important information. Include the information as text in your question.

Comment: Weather it's text or a .jpg of the text is a irreverent; thanks for providing something to show the output you're getting...

Comment: You are going to have to explain a little bit more of what exactly you want to happen because there are several logic errors in your code. Do you want the function `Tr1` to return a result? And if so, what should this result be? `T/Tc1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do not replace `Tr1` function value, to avoid such replacement change:

   ```
   Tr1_value = Tr1(T, Tc1)
   ```
2. Call `Bzero1` function with code:

   ```
   Bzero1(Tr1_value)
   ```
3. Modify `Tr1` to return value:

   ```
   def Tr1(T, Tc1):
       result = T/Tc1
       print("Relative temperature 1: ", result)
       return result
   ```

Also, let me suggest you to take a look on [python official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/) - there you can learn  a lot about python ...

**Good Luck !**

Comment: Currently the OP's `Tr1` function doesn't return anything, so your `Tr1_value` is always going to be `None`, which is probably not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll take a look on that tutorial, since I'm just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

`def` is only defining a function, not calling it. E.g.

```
def foo(a):
    print a * 2
```

means there is now a function `foo` that takes argument `a`. The `a` in `foo(a)` is the name of the variable *inside* the function.

So in your case

```
def Bzero1(Tr1):
  print("Bzero 1: ", 0.083-(0.422/Tr1**1.6))
```

defines the function Bzero1 as taking argument `Tr1`, but doesn't call it. You need to call the function, just like you called `Tr1`:

```
Bzero1(Tr1)
```

You can see that this way it becomes confusing quite quickly on which is a variable outside of your function, and which are variables inside functions. Therefore it is better to use different names for variables in your outer program v.s. those inside functions.

Here are a few more best practices that you might find useful:

- It is generally better to first define all functions and then execute the program's main code, as opposed to intermixing function definitions and the main program.
- Another best practice is to make functions only calculate output from inputs, and handle output somewhere else. This way you get to reuse your functions in other parts of your program while always keeping control of when and what to output to the user.
- Finally, you shouldn't generally reassign names, e.g. `Tr1 = Tr1(...)` means that `Tr1` is now no longer the name of the function but the name of the result returned by Tr1. In short, use different names for different things.

Applying these tips, your code might look as follows:

```
# function definitions first
def Tr1(vt, vtc1):
  return vt/vtc1

def Bzero1(vtr1):
  return 0.083-(0.422 / vtr1 ** 1.6)

# get user input
T = float(input("Introduce system temperature in Kelvin: ")) 
print("System temperature is: ", T)

vTc1 = float(input("Introduce critical temperature of component 1: ")) 
print("Critical temperature of component 1 is: ", vTc1)

# run calculations
vTr1 = Tr1(T, vTc1)
vBz1 = Bzero1(vTr1)

# print output
print("Relative temperature 1: ", vTr1)
print("Bzero 1: ", vBz1)
```

**Note**

Since I don't know the semantic meaning of your variables I have just used small letter `v` as a prefix - in general it is better to use meaningful names like `temperature` or `temp1` and `temp2` etc. Programs are not math papers.

Comment: The `Tr1` function needs to return some value, otherwise `vTr1` is always going to be `None`.